# I want to extract name from CV

Tags: text-mining

I want to extract name from CV. 
I need high level if accuracy more than 95 %. I have started with taking assumptions that it is highly likely to be found in 10% top lines or if not there then in some section similar to Personal details.
Can u plz  provide any help/guidance ?

Comment: Plain text file, Word document, PDF, RTF, HTML, LaTeX source, PostScript file, document scan in image format?

Answer (score 1):

Since CV data is mostly structured you can use [Stanford NER](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml) for named entity recognition or use [CRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_random_field) to train and model your own named entity recognizer.